# how i can do permissions in php with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have builded small php script that include topics, users, comments, user profile and sessions with Codeigniter framework but i do not know now how to do permissions for users,

I mean how to make only registered people can add topics and comments and somethings like that

I try to make it by sessions

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
{
    // here something like add topic or comment buttons 
}
```

do i right ? this is only the way to do permissions ? or there's any another way better ?

Comment: Without knowing how your user part (i.e. users table and related models controllers) is made, it would be hard to say. But your code is on good way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the version of CI that you use but for 2.x (CodeIgniter v3 requires the class names to be ucfirst().) I have found ion_auth to be quite good and very stylable. You can get it here.http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/
It has some nice touches where you can restrict certain views/pages or methods by an assigned group or the main 'logged_in' method.

The script to put in your construct is as simple as

```
     if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()){
              redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that such thing is available in ci but you can do it by using user_type or categorize your user.

Like for admin user_type = "admin" or 1

for customer user_type = "customer" or 2

i have implemented this thing in 2 yrs ago and till now never face any problem with it and even further modification like creating another group is real easy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have a table called "users" in the database, add a new column let's call it "privilege" in that table, it will contain the code for user privileges, let say 0 is for admin , 1 for customer, 2 for guest ...etc

and  let say only admin and customer can post a comment, so your code would check for the user privilege and decide accordingly.

pseudo code:

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
{
     // let say the user_id is loaded in the session
     $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

     $this->load->model('user_mdl');
     $user_priv = $this->user_mdl->get_user_priv($user_id);

     if($user_priv == 0 or $user_priv == 1)
     {
        // here something like add topic or comment buttons 
     }
    else
    {
      // sorry you don't have permission to do comment or something interesting 
    }


}
```

you can also create a new table "privileges" and link it (via a foreign key) to users if you want to normalize it instead of having a column in the users table.

hope that helps
cheers!